# Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image URL in a `imageUrl` variable and I am trying to set it as CSS style, using jQuery:

```
$('myObject').css('background-image', imageUrl);
```

This seems to be not working, as:

```
console.log($('myObject').css('background-image'));
```

returns `none`.

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  Is Jquery throwing an error?

Comment: No, its not setting it properly.  I am logging it and it is just not changing.

Comment: The first time jQuery doesn't try to guess what the user meant.

Answer (score 990, accepted):

You probably want this (to make it like a normal CSS background-image declaration):

```
$('myObject').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: I was doing it this way - but a space between 'url' and the left parentheses was causing my code to fail. Copy/pasted yours and realized the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I using your code in this script but get me background-image: url((unknown));
This is my script:
    var bg_img = jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').attr('data-src');    
    jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').on('mouseover',function() {    
      jQuery('.home-banner .bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg_img + ')');
    });
Any idea why?

Comment: url(<your url>) is not working for me. The value must be inside quotes i.e. url("<your url>") or url('<your url>').

Answer (score 79):

You'll want to include double quotes (") before and after the imageUrl like this:

```
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
```

This way, if the image has spaces it will still be set as a property.

Comment: in that case, it should be `$('myObject').css('background-image', 'url(' + encodeURIComponent(imageUrl) + ')');`

Comment: Quotes are not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-are-quotes-needed

Comment: This solved it for me. I needed to have the double quotes. My image names do contain spaces. Otherwise, nothing would occur. I could get something like `$('.myObject').css('background-color', 'green');`  to work, but not change the image without double quotes. Thanks!

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` won't work if part of your URL already contained URL escaped characters. You should escape potential double quote character in imageUrl though: `$('myObject').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '")');`

Comment: By the by, doing `$('#elem').css('background-image', 'url(' + encodeURIComponent(thumbData.url) + ')');` gave me `background-image: url("%2Ffiles%2Fusers%2Fthumbs%2F36206608-hd-pics-3.jpg");`

Answer (score 48):

Alternatively to what the others are correctly suggesting, I find it easier usually to toggle CSS classes, instead of individual CSS settings (especially background image URLs).  For example:

```
// in CSS 
.bg1 
{
  background-image: url(/some/image/url/here.jpg);
}

.bg2 
{
  background-image: url(/another/image/url/there.jpg);
}

// in JS
// based on value of imageUrl, determine what class to remove and what class to add.
$('myOjbect').removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do things because it lets you use a css pre processor.

Comment: This is great, much better than the more direct solution.

Comment: This is going to load both images though.

Comment: Is this actually a recommended solution? It seems like this unnecessarily requires more information, e.g. in case there is a third possible background image, you will need to remove all other background images, or alternatively keep track of the "current" image. 

And also to have configuration details, such as these URIs in the .css files drives me crazy. :smiley: I have to search all over the code!

Comment: Using classes like this is also my preference since it lets you keep a clean seperation between code and style.  I can then change all my images and animations in the css (via media selectors and such) without messing about with the code.  You don't have to search all over the code if you keep your images OUT of the code!

Comment: @sheriffderek: I don't think so. It applies only one class at a time to the element

Answer (score 16):

Here is my code:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url("/apo/1.jpg")');
```

Enjoy, friend

Answer (score 13):

Further to the other answers, you can also use "background". This is particularly useful when you want to set other properties relating to the way the image is used by the background, such as:

```
$("myObject").css("background", "transparent url('"+imageURL+"') no-repeat right top");
```

Comment: This answer made more sense when I thought the original op had used background not background-image.  I've modified my answer to make more sense, and I'll leave this here for posterity anyway.

Answer (score 12):

The problem I was having, is that I kept adding a semi-colon `;` at the end of the `url()` value, which prevented the code from working.

❌ ***NOT WORKING CODE:***

```js
$('#image_element').css('background-image', 'url(http://example.com/img.jpg);');
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

✅ **WORKING CODE:**

```
$('#image_element').css('background-image', 'url(http://example.com/img.jpg)');
```

Notice the omitted semi-colon `;` at the end in the working code. I simply didn't know the correct syntax, and it's really hard to notice it. Hopefully this helps someone else in the same boat.

Comment: This works perfectly as jQuery can append it to style property.

Answer (score 7):

For those using an actual URL and not a variable:

```
$('myObject').css('background-image', 'url(../../example/url.html)');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try modifying the "style" attribute:

```
$('myObject').attr('style', 'background-image: url("' + imageUrl +'")');
```

Comment: will replace all other styles. Not recommended

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that the jQuery css function allows objects to be passed which allows you to set multiple items at the same time. The answered code would then look like this:

`$(this).css({'background-image':'url(' + imageUrl + ')'})`

Comment: This should be upvoted. Totally got used to the syntax `.css( {...} )`

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation to the rescue.

```
let imageUrl = 'imageurl.png';
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', `url(${imageUrl})`);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$('myObject').css({'background-image': 'url(imgUrl)',});
```

Comment: This won't work because the url is encased in single quotes.