# Changing background image using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have this jquery code that changes the image of the background on click:

```
$('a.note').click(function(){
  $('#full').css('background-image','img/1.jpg');

});
```

However, it's not changing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to include the `url()` part of the `background-image` property.

```
$('#full').css('background-image','url(img/1.jpg)');
```

Comment: how do i remove it the backround image on click function!!! thanks :)) +upvote from me

Comment: @getaway: Set it to an empty string. `.css('background-image','');`

Comment: thanks you very much, i will accept the answer when it lets me lol!!

Comment: @getaway: Come to think of it, a more appropriate way to remove the image is probably to set it to "none" `.css('background-image','none');` since that is the correct value for no background image. http://www.css3.com/css-background-image/

Comment: I would also like to note that there should be NO space between "url" and "(". That was driving me nuts for a couple of hours.