# Jquery.css not applying Background-Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some Javascript which fires after an Ajax post.

> When the javascript fires I want the `<section class="section-1653">` to be given a different background image to the one specified in the CSS file.

I am running the following code and I can see the Font Size being set, but the background image is not.

> Why is the background image property not being set?

```
$("section.section-1653").css({"background-image": backgroundImageUrl,font-size": "200%"});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background image using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578714/changing-background-image-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image needs to be within url ()

```
$("section.section-1653").css({"background-image": "url("+backgroundImageUrl+")", "font-size": "200%"});
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs be set like:

```
$("section.section-1653").css({"background-image", "url('+ imageUrl +'), "font-size": "200%"});
```