# Change backgroundimage url of masterpage on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I was wonder if there was a way to change a background image with a button click. The body background for my master page is in my external CSS sheet. I am not sure that this can be done with c#. My css code is like this.

```
body{
background-image: url(/images/image.jpg)
}
```

I have updated my code, however it is not working correctly the image does not stay changed it flickers the new pic for a second but doesnt change it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button2').click(function () {
                $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/Image/image.jpg)')
            });
        });
```

Comment: Other than a missing semicolon and a `);` at the end of your function, your code seems fine . What is the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET renames the ID's of Controls when using a Master page. So depending of where the javascript function is you need to use `ClientID`

If the script is on the child page along with the button you do this

```
$('#<%= ButtonChild.ClientID %>').click(function () {
```

If the button is on the master, but the script is on the child you have to navigate up the control tree

```
$('#<%= Master.FindControl("ButtonMaster").ClientID %>').click(function () {
```

And when a button is clicked it will trigger a PostBack, so you might want to add return false;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= ButtonChild.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $('body').css('background', 'url(/images/image.jpg)');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're referencing your button correctly through jQuery (use a # for id references).

```
$('#button1').click(function() { 
   $('body').css('background','url(/images/image.jpg)') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button1').click(function() {
('body').css('background-image','url(/images/image.jpg)')
}
```

its a duplicate question to the following question:

[Changing background image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578714/changing-background-image-using-jquery)

Comment: My code is not working correctly the background doesnt stay changed it just flickers and briefly shows the image it is supposed to change to. Here is my code:$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Button2').click(function () {
                    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/Image/image.jpg)')
                });
            });