# Primefaces: how to change the default icon on the button of the calendar field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces, how do I change the icon that is being used by the button of the calendar field?

For example, in the following field

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date3}" id="popupButtonCal" showOn="button" />
```

I want to change the icon to http://forum.primefaces.org/images/smilies/icon_e_wink.gif.

I've looked at the [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/calendar.html), but I cannot find an attribute for this.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following, with partial success:

JSF:

```
<p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button" icon="ui-calendar"/>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-widget .ui-calendar {

    background-image: url(#{resource['images:country_flag.gif']});
}
```

**PROBLEMS:**

1. I do see the image on the `p:commandButton` button now. But, I am getting the warning message:

   `Apr 03, 2012 10:43:58 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
   WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, images/country_flag.gif.jsf.`
2. I could not find a css style on the `p:calendar` that I should override in order to change the image on the calendar button.

Comment: replace default image with yours

Comment: Thanks. But I would not like to change the primefaces jar.

Comment: @Cagatay Civici could you please provide an example/link? Thanks.

Comment: how about this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/512067/617373

Comment: you tried it with el expression in css file which cannot be done... in the link they do it with jquery...

Comment: @Daniel EL expression was translated correctly - that's why I can see the image. Why do you think that EL cannot be used in a CSS file? If I don't want to use EL, I can use physical path in my css, I don't have to use jQuery for that (I assume I should get the same result). But I do not understand why I am getting the warning.

Comment: sorry haven't really looked into u'r EL... so its my bad... how about something like that url('#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/country_flag.gif');   does it throws an error (info) message too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
.ui-icon-calendar {
    background-image: <your URL> !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```