# Restore Primefaces 2.x look and feel on some components

Tags: primefaces

One of the web application I developed uses Primefaces 2.2. I'm delaying the migration to 3.X because I think the users are more comfortable with the 'old' look and feel of some components.
In the calendar I liked the 2.2 icon on the popup button and I would like to go on with it. Unfortunately it seems the easy way to achieve this goal, the attribute popupIcon, is no more supported, despite it is still present in the guide for 3.X

FileUpload was completely rewritten and its look is radically changed: now in the auto mode the browse (choose file) button is inside a rounded box with a background image and color set. I preferred the 2.X look, where there is no rounded box.  Besides making some tests with Internet Explorer 9 I noticed the UploadedFile.getFileName() gives now the full path of the file, while I have functioning code expecting only the file name without path. The migration guide tells nothing about this change which is completely undocumented.

I believe the original look and feel can be restored with some css override, but I have already tried without success reading also this

[Primefaces: how to change the default icon on the button of the calendar field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981076/primefaces-how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-button-of-the-calendar-field)

and I would like to receive some advices.
My major concern is that css modifications can affect other components, so it is necessary to be very specific.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick fix, in fact I think it will be a lot of work. As you said yourself, the look and feel for some elements has changed a lot. However PrimeFaces is highly customizable when it comes to styling.

I suggest you download the manual from the PrimeFaces site (PDF) and get to work using CSS as your weapon of choice. Maybe you can re-use the CSS of PrimeFaces 2.x as a reference.