# Swapping images using jQuery in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to swap the background image of an element in set sequence to create an animation where each image is a different frame and it should iterate through the frames until it reaches the last frame and then return to the beginning again.

My code is as follows:

```
$spinner_currentFrame = 1;

            function UpdateSpinner(target, numFrames)
            {
                $spinner_currentFrame = ($spinner_currentFrame) + 1;
                if($spinner_currentFrame > numFrames) {
                    $spinner_currentFrame = 1;
                }
                $(target).css("background-image", "frame-" + $spinner_currentFrame + ".jpg");
            }

            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $spinner_loadingAnim = setInterval(function ()
                {
                    UpdateSpinner('#spinner', 300);
                },
                24);
            });
```

The reason I'm not using a sprite is because I have a few hundred images and the frames have been exported from Flash like `frame-1.jpg, frame-2.jpg`. However my code isn't reporting any errors but the background image isn't been added... Any ideas? Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-image` css property needs to be set with `url("/path/frame-1.jpg")`.

```
$(target).css("background-image", "url('frame-" + $spinner_currentFrame + ".jpg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but doesn't it have to be like

```
$(target).css("background-image", "url(frame-" + $spinner_currentFrame + ".jpg)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(target).css("background-image", "url('frame-" + $spinner_currentFrame + ".jpg')");
```

like the question [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

edit- typo