# How to set image to be <canvas> background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a project that will have a table and canvas field below the table.

I need to put one of the pictures to be a background and it was in my case tshirt.png.

Until now I have done the following. I have two files (index.html & jQuery.js)

index

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
 </head>
   <table border="1">
        <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>filename</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>z</td>
        </tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><img src="images/sheep.png" width="40px" height="40px"></img></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="x"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="y"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="z"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><img src="images/tshirt.png" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item.png</td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
   </tr>
    </table>

   <section id="main">
   <canvas  id="canvas" width="1024" height="768" style="border:1px solid red;">    
   </canvas>
   </section>
</html>
```

jQuery.js

```
function doFirst(){
    var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = x.getContext('2d');

    var pic = new Image();
    pic.src = "images/sheep.png";
    pic.addEventListener("load", function() { canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0,100,200)}, false);

    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "images/tshirt.png";
    background.addEventListener("load",function(){
        canvas.drawImage(background,0,250,200,300)}, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: why don't you use css background?

Comment: How would it be in my case? If you could write the code I would be very grateful?

Comment: I don't know how it would be in your case because your intention is not clear, what you want to do here.. Do you know how to set a background in css?

Comment: I want to set tshirt.png to be the background (background.src = "images/tshirt.png";).
. I do not have a big experience in working with CSS. Additional problems it's giving me because the image is loaded from jQuery.js.

Comment: ok.. but why do you load the image via js?
check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/eukVv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eukVv/1/

Answer (score 0):

The canvas certainly takes a different mindset and approach but remember sometimes to take a step back and think of a more 'simple' approach, this will help from over engineering your code.

Just use CSS to define the background

```
background: url("images/tshirt.png");
```

Here is how you can set it in [JavaScript via jQuery from a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Comment: That would not solve my problem. The project was such that I would have a table with rows of sheep and shirts for example.

Each row will have coordinates x, y, z. 
If I change the coordinates of the tshirt(background) or sheep.png  in the table will be moved on canvas. 

That's what I get at the end of the project. 

This way you offered me a solution if I delete:
 var background = new Image();
 background.src = "images/tshirt.png";
 background.addEventListener("load",function(){
 canvas.drawImage(background,0,250,200,300)}, false);

and just write in css
background: url("images/tshirt.png");

Comment: It will not displayed tshirt.png as the background.

Comment: So are you wanting an image for each row then...for example...the sheep row has a background of sheep.png...and the shirts row has a background of shirts.png?

Is the canvas in behind your table?