# jQuery slideshow that only changes class

Tags: jquery, html, class, slider, slideshow

I have a quite special slideshow where 5 slides are custom responsive HTML codes.

I'm looking for a jQuery slideshow that would *only* just put certain class to the active slide. No transisions or position change whatsoever. My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="active">first slide</div>
    <div>second slide</div>
    <div>third slide</div>
</div>
```

The slideshow  should have buttons *prev*, *next* and buttons representing each slide. After click on such a button, the `active` class would jump to requested slide. It should also have autoplay. In other words, controls like any other normal slideshow.

Is there an existing slideshow solution that I could use?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to create your own slideshow or use jQuery slider plugin?

Comment: Do you mean http://jqueryui.com/slider/? No, I want a slideshow. My question was for existing solution?

Comment: no i mean nivo slider http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

Comment: No, Nivo Slider changes X/Y position and I dont want that at all. I'm thinking about coding it by myself. Maybe there's no such simple slideshow.

Comment: Check out This Answer I posted (Which was choosed as best ans.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293523/review-slider-using-css-html-and-or-jquery-or-java/22293785#22293785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider div:first-child').addClass('active');

    $('.arrow').on('click', function(){
        updateClass( $(this).attr('data-dir') );
    });

});

function updateClass ( direction )
{
    var current = $('#slider .active');

    if ( direction == 'left' && current.index() > 0 )
    {
        current.removeClass('active');
        current.prev().addClass('active');
    }
    else if ( direction == 'right' && current.index() < $('#slider div:last-child').index() )
    {
        current.removeClass('active');
        current.next().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="arrow" data-dir="left">left</a>
<div id="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="arrow" data-dir="right">right</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that could partly do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jssor slider http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html

It should work fine for the current jquery version

**Jquery**

```
<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 
600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He doesnt want slideshow