# Add background-image using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my script I have variable `image_src` like

```
var image_src = 'img/test.jpg';
```

then I tried to add `background-image` to block using jQuery

```
$('#lightbox').css({
        'background-image': '(../' + image_src + ')'
    });
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `url` in set value.try this:

```
 $('#lightbox').css({
    'background-image': 'url(../' + image_src + ')'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your CSS property with a [URL datatype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/uri):

```
$('#lightbox').css({
   'background-image': 'url(../' + image_src + ')'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What error message are you getting?

This should work:

```
$('#lightbox').css({
   'background-image': 'url(../' + image_src + ')'
});
```