# Change img src on click in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image which changes based on clicking on images in a list.

The only trouble is, the images in the list have their url embedded in a style as a background-image.

How would I call the url of the img src to the new image?

> `<ul id="swatchList_att1"><li class="Name AttributeSwatch In_stock colourSwatch" id="attributeSwatch_1" data-attname="att1" data-attvalue="Deep Blue (001)" data-atrsku="0012345" style="background-image: url(https://color.adobe.com/api/v2/themes/2022184.png);">`

**EDIT**

Wow, great response time.

and

Wow, I phrased this incredibly poorly yesterday. Apologies.

The list "swatchList_att1" is a group of color swatches which are shrunk to 50% of the jpeg size.

All I'm trying to do is create a sort of "Preview" image which sits in a different div and will show a selected color swatch at an inflated size (110%). On page load, it would be the first color in the list. When a click occurs on a color in the group of color swatches, the "Preview" image would change to what color was clicked.

I can't make changes to how these list items work (i.e. change it to "data-background") because the functionality behind the scenes would break. Annoyingly, I can't do much about that. These list objects need to have their image defined in "style", for whatever reason (I don't know). I can, however, add an onclick function to the list (if I had something that could apply it to all items in the list, which all have very long and different names).

Thus I need to extrapolate the url from the "style" onclick and have "Preview" img src change to that url.

*In response to BearSkyView:*

*Since it's a seperate image, this isn't exactly what I meant. Also, I'd need something which applied an onclick to everything in the list.*

*In response to somethinghere:*

*That is more closely along the lines of what I'd like to accomplish, but as I can't change the way these list objects are made, this sadly won't work for me.*

Comment: Or don't use an image, just set a div with the same background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Comment: What does "call the url of the img src to the new image" mean?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/css/

`$('#attributeSwatch_1').css("background-image", new src here);`

EDIT: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rsqtL805/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"url('" + new_src + "')"`?

Comment: First of, either you add another `'` after `attributeSwatch_1` or you remove the first one. Second, I thought the question was 'how do I get my image URLs into another element', which this does not sufficiently address. Third, @BartZalezski - either thats true or not, depending on what BearSkyView meant. Its true if he has extracted the URL, its false if he just copied the original source from a `li`.

Comment: Look at the documentation I linked Barth. Proper syntax would be $('#attributeSwatch_1').css('background-image', 'url(https://something.edu/theimage.png)');

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `data-attributes` anyway, why don't you put it into one? Say `data-background="URL"`.

```
<img src="" id="myImageElement" alt="large image" />
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" data-background="path/to/image.jpg" onclick="setImg(this); return false;" alt="thumbnail" />

function setImg(obj){
    var img = obj.getAttribute('data-background');
    document.getElementById("myImageElement").attribute("src", img);
}
```

Otherwise you can read the background image property and split it in javascript to retrieve the URL and do with it as you like:

```
var img = this.style.backgroundImage;
    img = img.split("rl(")[1].split(")")[0];
```

The above will take the following string:

```
url(path/to/image.jpg);
```

And split it first into:

```
[0] => u
[1] => path/to/image.jpg)
```

And then we split the element at place 1 at the `)` and select the remainder at index 0.

```
[0] => path/to/image.jpg
[1] =>
```

With that you could do

```
document.getElementById("myImageElement").attribute("src", img);
```

to set the src of the image element to the just retrieved source.