# How to change the background image of input button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a input a button which have a initial background image. I tried to change its image when some condition changed with jquery .css(). It seems that it will override the button's global css in css file. How can I only change background attribute with jquery or anything else? Thanks.

JS:

```
if(sum>=window.start_fee){
    $(".shopcart").removeAttr("disabled")
    $(".shopcart").css("background", 'url(/static/images/cart2.png)')
}else{
    $(".shopcart").attr("disabled","disabled")
    $(".shopcart").css("background", 'url(/static/images/cart.png)')
}
```

css:

```
.shopcart{
     background:url(/static/images/cart.png) no-repeat; 
     border:none; 
     background-size:100% 100%; 
     width:57px; height:50px; 
     float:right;
}
```

Comment: The code you have is correct. It's not going to alter any global CSS, just change the specific class you targeted. If you reload the page it will revert to what's in your CSS file.

Comment: Hope this would be useful [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is create a class disabled in css, in this way you separate the presentation of logic. Sample

**CSS**

```
.shopcart{
     background:url(/static/images/cart2.png) no-repeat; 
     border:none; 
     background-size:100% 100%; 
     width:57px; height:50px; 
     float:right;
}

.shopcart.disabled{
     background:url(/static/images/cart.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

In JS you just add or remove the disabled class, sample:

**JS**

```
if(sum>=window.start_fee){
    $(".shopcart").removeClass("disabled");
}else{
    $(".shopcart").addClass("disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Remove attr you can use addClass and removeClass property

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(sum>=window.start_fee){
    $("input[type=submit]").removeClass("submitbtn");
    $("input[type=submit]").addClass("submitbtnnew");   
}
else{
    $("input[type=submit]").addClass("submitbtn");
    $("input[type=submit]").removeClass("submitbtnnew");

}

});
</script>
```

Apply your background image for that class

```
<style>
.submitbtn{
    background:#000;
}
.submitbtnnew{
    background:#03C;
}
</style>
```