# How to set background Image with with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set background image of a div
for that I am trying

```
var a = "http://media1.santabanta.com/full2/Indian%20%20Celebrities(F)/Sonam%20Kapoor/sonam-kapoor-40a.jpg";
$("#login-cover").css('background-image', 'url("' + a + '");');
```

but it is not showing image as background. Console is not showing any error

I tried above **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/07oo4own/)**

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property

Comment: @suchit I have seen this but I was not able to find mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `;` like below

```
$("#login-cover").css('background-image', 'url("' + a + '")');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/07oo4own/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You have a `;` at the end of the css value

```js
var a = "http://media1.santabanta.com/full2/Indian%20%20Celebrities(F)/Sonam%20Kapoor/sonam-kapoor-40a.jpg";
$("#login-cover").css('background-image', 'url("' + a + '")');
```

```css
#login-cover {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#wrap {
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="login-cover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in place of your javascript

```
var a= "http://media1.santabanta.com/full2/Indian%20%20Celebrities(F)/Sonam%20Kapoor/sonam-kapoor-40a.jpg"; 
$("#login-cover").css('background', 'url("' + a + '")'); // You had an un-needed semi-colon in your 2nd parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#login-cover").css('background-image', 'url("' + a + '")');`