# Jquery is not working with background change of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html button but i am unable to change it background with Jquery.

```
<html>
  <head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_2x.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="func_btns.js"></script> </head>
  <body bgcolor='#454545'><br />
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="button" value="Button #1" name="sname" class="btn2" /><br/><br />
        <input type="button" value="Button #2" name="sclass" class="btn2"/>
    </form>                                 
  </body>
</html>
```

and Here is func_btns.js File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('btn2').css('background-image', 'btna.jpg');
});
```

Simple JS code work but this peace of code is not working, i have download latest jquery and attach to html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the similar topic [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Try something like this,

```
 $('.btn2').css('background-image', 'url("btna.jpg")');
```

Comment: thanks it works, can you tell me what was error in my jq code

Comment: first, $('.btn2') missing '.'; second, using 'url("btna.jpg")' instead of ''btna.jpg''. Glad hearing it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.` to use class selector , that is `$(".btn2")`