# How to use a variable for img src?

Tags: jquery, css, variables, background-image, src

I am using this script to get the image src of an article's primary image

```
var someimage = $("body").find(".default-content").find('img').attr("src");
```

now I want to pass that var into my

```
background: url();
```

This will be the background image of the header but it will be different for each article page. Is there a way to use the var as the src or could this be done with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
var someimage = $("body").find(".default-content").find('img').attr("src");.

// set background url
$('#someblock').attr('style','background-image: url('+someimage +')');
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using `$('.header-class').css('background-image', 'url(' + someimage + ')');`, where you replace `.header-class` with... your header's classname.

[You can read up on it here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')')`

Comment: The syntax is wrong in this answer and will not work, and this should be closed as a duplicate