# Setting background image dynamically ul/li div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in website development and trying to figure out how to set image dynamically in `ul`/`li` `div` element. Below is my code in html file :

```
<div class="results">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="template hidden col-md-3">
            <div class="image">
                <!--img src='broken_file.png'-->
                <data>
                    <span class="name"></span>
                    <span data-before='faces' class="faces"></span>
                    <span data-before='genus' class="genus"></span>
                    <span data-before='vertices' class="vertices"></span>
                </data>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And from another js file I am trying to access the 'image' div as

```
$(li).find('image').css()
```

I am trying to set an image url inside `css()`, but not sure how I can do it, or even it is possible?

Comment: Provide actual code. Please. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your jQuery syntax is incorrect. `li` should be in quotes as it's a string, and the `image` selector requires a preceding `.` as it's a class. Finally, you can set the `background-image` in CSS, like this:

```
$('li').find('.image').css('background-image', 'url("my-image.png")');
```

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want to insert img tag into div with "image" class  -

```
$('li').find('.image').append($('<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/000/">'))
```

2) If you want to change  src attr -

```
    $('li').find('.image img').attr('src','http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/000/">')
```