# how to load random background image in css to a particular div using its class / jquery

Tags: javascript

this is the code am using for random images .

```
 var image = [];

 image[0] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripmeetup/image1.jpg" ;
 image[1] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripmeetup/image2.jpg";
 image[2] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripmeetup/image3.jpg";
 image[3] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripmeetup/image4.JPG";
 var size = image.length

 var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

   $("apt_banner").css({"background-image": "url(" +image[x]+ ")"});
```

in html

but the above code is not working for me . dont know where am going wrong

Comment: Don't use the `var image = new Array()` syntax, it is deprecated in favour of `var image = []`

Comment: what is the correct way to use it

Comment: ...I refer you to my previous comment. Use square brackets to declare an array instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Comment: @JonathanBrooks deprecated? Where do you read it? That you said is a shorthand but `new Array()` is not deprecated. Is the object instance. Share with us where do you read this.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code, can you post the html?

Comment: thank you i corrected  it . <img id="random"> is the code am using in html . am able to load images randomly . but i want to know how to load the same from css background

Comment: @SantoshKumar learn to ask in stackoverflow. You can't put a block of code and no explanation of how do you attempt or what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The convention is deprecated, not the standard

Comment: I need documentation to trust in that you say. Here you are a deprecated and obsolete functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features there isn't `new Array()` in nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

This should do,    `myOjbect` this should be your selector ( class, id or may be `<body>` tag)

```
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' +image[x]+ ')');
```

Comment: i want to set the background height and width . how can i do it ?

Comment: eg : use .css({'height':'900','width':'300'}) like this. And yes if it solved mark this answer as accepted

Comment: its not working . i want to add the background image to only a particular div . but the image is loading in the background of full page

Comment: than you have use that div's id or class (selector)

Comment: if i use the class of that particular div images are not loading