# How should I properly structure this "if" statement using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, parse-platform

I've written an if statement that checks if there is a current user and if so, grab that currentUser's profile image url from my DB and place it in a div. I've successfully done so with the following logic:

```
  function checkLogin() {

    if (Parse.User.current()) {
      var profilePicUrl = Parse.User.current().get("profile_picture").url();

      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url("+profilePicUrl+")");
    } else {

      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");
    }
  };
```

However the issue is, when there is a user that doesn't have a profile image, it throws an error. I've attempted to offset this by adding the following `else if` statement between the original two:

```
 function checkLogin() {

    if (Parse.User.current()) {
      var profilePicUrl = Parse.User.current().get("profile_picture").url();

      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url("+profilePicUrl+")");

    } else if (Parse.User.current() && !profilePicUrl){

      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");

    } else {

      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");

    }
  };
```

Now I'm almost certain I'm using the && operator wrong here, but what I'm trying to say in the middle `else if` is "if there is a current user & they don't have a profile image ..."

How do I properly state this?

Comment: The second case will never be used, because the first case will always be true before it (unless `Parse.User.current()` changes the return value between calls).

Comment: Why just not setting default image for user in DB when it creates ?

Comment: @7urkm3n how would i go about doing so? I'd love that option

Comment: it all depends on your back-end. What r u using for back-end? Also @DelightedD0D `js` version should work try his post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, since `parseObject.get()` returns `null` if the key is not found, all you need here is:

```
 function checkLogin() {
    if (user = Parse.User.current()) {
      var profilePic = user.get("profile_picture");
      var profilePicUrl = profilePic ? profilePic.url() : "//default image";  
      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url("+profilePicUrl+")");
    }
  };
```

Note that the `var someVar = someVar ? valueA : valueB;` syntax is a [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I just wanted to post mine, close to this )

Comment: this does away with the error, however rather than displaying the default image for a user with no profile image stored, it just shows a blank div

Comment: @JohnDurand have you replaced `//default image` with the actual path to your image?

Comment: change this one `"url(//default image)"` to `"default image url path"`

Comment: @HaykoKoryun no it cant because you still need to call `.url()` on the result of `.get("profile_picture")` but calling it when the value is `null` will thrown an  error

Comment: @7urkm3n no, this is the correct syntax see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property

Comment: @JohnDurand when you look at the console are there any 404 errors for that image?

Comment: @DelightedD0D u passing it like this `"url(url(//default image))"` in that case

Comment: @JohnDurand see my update, 7urkm3n pointed out my copy paste mistake :)

Comment: No worries, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the profile pic url before checking it and add a try/catch as a safety net (since I don't know the implementation of `current` and `url` methods)

```
function checkLogin() 
{
    try
    {
      var profilePicUrl = Parse.User.current().get("profile_picture").url();
      if (Parse.User.current() && profilePicUrl) 
      {
        $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url("+profilePicUrl+")");
      } 
      else 
      {
        $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");
      }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      console.log("unexpected error occured");
      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");
    }
  };
```

Comment: `.get("profile_picture").url()` will throw an error when get returns `null`, I know you put the try catch there to protect against that, but worth metioning

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes since implementation of url and current methods are not shared.

Answer (score -1):

try this .....

```
var profilePicUrl = null;//assign some empty value here...

if (Parse.User.current()) {
      profilePicUrl = Parse.User.current().get("profile_picture").url();   

 } 
if(Parse.User.current() && profilePicUrl ){

     $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url("+profilePicUrl+")");
}
else if (Parse.User.current() && !profilePicUrl){

     $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");

} else {
      $(".user-image").css("background-image", "url(//default image)");
}
```

Comment: `.get("profile_picture").url()` will throw an error when get returns `null` and this is super redundant