# Javascript to change attribute under CSS

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

**document.getElementById("Id1").style.*backgroundImage* = "url(value)";**

to change the background image attribute in the CSS.
But, the attribute used in CSS is

> background-Image

Why we **can't** use the same name under Javascript as
**document.getElementById("Id1").style.*background-Image* = "url(value)";**

Comment: I recommend you to use jQuery instead of javascript

Comment: Have a look at this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property> Maybe this can help?

Comment: If you want I can show you how jQuery works

Comment: @eronax59 [You're joking right?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)

Comment: @4castle its only for you dear

Comment: document.getElementById("Id1").css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')'); try with this

Comment: @PankajGupta `element.css` is not a function - I think you're thinking jQuery is in some way even remotely relevant to the question ... I'll spare you the research ... it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX you are correct sorry my mistake

Answer (score 2):

As @Bitwise Creative said, you can't use `-` out of string. Instead you can do this,

```
document.getElementById("Id1").style["background-image"] = "url(value)";
```

If you use document.getElementById("Id1").style.background-Image = "url(value)", what will happen means javascript consider as statement before '-' "document.getElementById("Id1").style.background" and image consider as variable. So you will get syntax error