# Page background Images are not changing on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the background image when the user scrolls the page. The code I have written is not working. I am running this code on a WordPress website. Below Is my code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( jQuery ) {
    jQuery(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() >= jQuery('#one').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#one').attr('data-src'));
        }

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > jQuery('#two').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#two').attr('data-src'));
        }

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > jQuery('#three').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#three').attr('data-src'));
        }

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > jQuery('#four').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#four').attr('data-src'));
        }

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > jQuery('#five').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#five').attr('data-src'));
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here I have five sections and I gave an ID to my section as I define on the code. Below is how I added the 'data-src' attribute to the particular section through the elementor data attribute option.

data-src|http://www.kasundev.xyz/design/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/WhatsApp-Image-2022-02-10-at-11.00.38.jpeg

This is the CSS I am using when the page loads first. This code applies to the whole page.

```
body {
  background:#333333;
  transition: all 1200ms ease-out;
  will-change: background;
}
```

My question is nothing is changing when I scroll. Instead of an image If I give a color like this
data-color|#000000 will change.

How I change my background image when scrolling. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting background-image using jQuery CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512054/setting-background-image-using-jquery-css-property)

Comment: @showdev thanks for trying to help me. Yes, adding a URL helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add url('image path') around the image.